# TcpClientでTCP接続がうまくできない

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tcp

クライアントPC1台+サーバーPC2台(A、B)という構成で、
クライアントPCからサーバAにtcp接続を行い、コネクション確立されたらAに、確立されなければBにアクセスするというソフトを作成しています。

TCPポート50002を指定して接続確認を行いたいのですが、うまく行えません。
ファイアウォールの送受信設定で50002を許可にはしています。

下記が実装中のTCPアクセスクラスです。

```
public class TcpClientAcs
{
    string strPartnerIpAddress;
    int nPort;
    int nTcpConnectionTimeout;
    int nTcpConnectionCount;


    public TcpClientAcs()
    {
        nPort = 50002;
        nTcpConnectionTimeout = 2000;
        nTcpConnectionCount = 2;           
    }

    public bool CLTMain(string ipaddress)
    {
        strPartnerIpAddress = ipaddress;
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcp;        
        int ConnectionRetryCnt = 0;
        tcp = null;

        // TCP connection
        while (true)
        {

            if (ConnectionRetryCnt < nTcpConnectionCount)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcp = new TcpClient();
                    var connection = tcp.BeginConnect(strPartnerIpAddress, nPort, null, null);
                    var success = connection.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(nTcpConnectionTimeout);
                    //add retry count
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        ConnectionRetryCnt++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ConnectionRetryCnt++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「うまく行えません」とは何が期待値と異なるのでしょうか？

Comment: コネクションで失敗してしまいます。コネクションに成功できれば次の処理を実行。というようような処理になっています。接続先サーバーのIPアドレス(ping確認済)は合っています。tcpConnection時に指定したポート番号以外もFWで有効化しなければならないなどあるでしょうか？

Comment: つながらないという結果は事実でしょうが、その原因がコードにあるか別問題かは外部の人には判断できないですね。

Comment: もしも、Exceptionが発生してるならその詳細を確認してみるとなにかヒントがあるかもしれません。

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。回答いただきありがとうございます。
自己解決したため、別途回答欄に記載しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Wiresharkで調べたところ送信元のポート番号が毎回異なることに気づきました。
今回の場合、送信先のポート番号のみ指定しており、送信元のポート番号を指定していなかった為、起きていました。
TcpClientのインスタンス作成時にIPEndpointを指定することで解決できました。

```
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, nPort);
tcp = new TcpClient(ep);
```

Comment: もしよければ、この回答に回答マークをつけてもらえますか？そうすると、この質問が解決済みというステータスに更新されます。